# Software for remote controlling a computer with Kubuntu

Tags: kubuntu, remote-control

I have a father who is totally lost with computers. From time to time, he calls me and says there's something wrong with the computer, but he cannot quite explain what the problem is. I'm now installing a computer with Kubuntu for him, setting up everything for him so that he doesn't need to worry about anything, just click on the icons I've set for him on the desktop.

I know that I cannot avoid all problems by doing this (some problems are not OS related) and what I'd like to have is a software which I can use to remote control his computer. In other words, I'd like to capture his computer (with his permission, of course) and be able to see for myself what he actually is trying to do and to remotely SHOW him what he is supposed to do.

My question is, could you recommend me some software that does what I want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look into [**NoMachine**](http://www.nomachine.com/) or [**TightVNC**](http://www.tightvnc.com/). With past experience these offer the best performance if [**X forwarding**](http://wiki.linuxquestions.org/wiki/X11_forwarding_with_OpenSSH) is not an option (it can be tricky).

You can use [**xvncviewer**](http://www.fifi.org/cgi-bin/man2html/usr/X11R6/man/man1/xvncviewer.1x.gz) to control the active session.

Comment: NoMachine is really nice. However, I've not been successful yet at getting it to shadow a remote session. I probably just need to read the instructions more carefully. I'm guessing the built-in "System->Remote Desktop" using VNC will be the best option.

Comment: yes, if you want to see what the console is doing.  that or x11vnc can share the X session.  Xvnc4-server and TightVNC-server can run a separate X server that you can use at the same time, but they cannot attach to an X session in progress.

Comment: ah, missed the part where he said "remotely SHOW him what he is supposed to do", I thought he was just fixing something remotely. Updated.

Answer (score 1):

Kubuntu also comes with [Krfb](http://docs.kde.org/stable/en/kdenetwork/krfb/index.html).  I've never used it, but the application lets you invite others to view and/or control your desktop via network or Internet.